# Possible $ r $ to make the set become a subring of $ 2\times 2 $ matrices.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

> Suppose $ a, b, c, d $ are real numbers and $ r $ is a constant. Which values can $ r $ take to make the following set a subring of ring of $ 2\times 2 $ matrices: $$ \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}: a+b+c+d=r \right\} .$$

I was thinking one possibility that $ r=0 $, but I had trouble with showing the multiplication is closed. A little help here?

According to the post below, I'd like to add a paragraph:

Actually, the only possibility for $ r $ is $ 0 $, since the additional identity $ 0 $ must stay in there.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} a^{'} & b^{'}\\c^{'} &d^{'}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} aa^{'}+bc^{'} &ab^{'}+bd^{'}\\ca^{'}+dc^{'}&cb^{'}+dd^{'}\end{bmatrix} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the set can only be a subring, if it is an additive subgroup first. So the zero matrix should be in the set. This necessarily means $r=0$. Now multiply two such matrices. What do you get? Try to find a counterexample with specific matrices.

More explicitly, try
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 10 & 25 \cr 0 & -35 \end{pmatrix}
B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $AB$ is no longer in the set.

Comment: Hello! I think multiplying another matrix $ (a, b, c, d) $ satisfying $ a+b+c+d=0 $ is fine, the result still lies in the set, then why counterexample?

Comment: No, it does not! What did you take for $a,b,c,d$? Try $(10,25, 0,-35)$.

Comment: $ AB $ will be fine but not $ BA $. Thanks~